# Laravel 5.1 - Pass parameter to Breadcrumbs

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, breadcrumbs

I use davejamesmiller Breadcrumbs package. I am wondering how to pass a parameter to a breadcrumb, something like an id.

In the docs ([here](http://laravel-breadcrumbs.davejamesmiller.com/en/latest/advanced.html#passing-an-array-of-parameters)) it says that is possible, but can't find the way to do it.

My goal es to do a breadcrumb like this: `Dashboard \ User \ New Model`. Where New Model its a form to add model data with some relationship with the user. Without the user_id param the link for `User` won't  work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass global variable

```
\View::share ( 'variable2', $variable2 );
```

if render breadcrumbs in layout

or You need render breadcrumbs in  `user.new_model.blade

```
@section('content')
{!! Breadcrumbs::render('page', $page) !!}
@stop`
```

> my way

Create template

```
breadcrumbs.blade.php
```

with content

```
@if(!empty($breadcrumbs))
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li>{!! link_to_route('main', 'Home') !!}</li>
    @foreach($breadcrumbs as $bread)
        @if(isset($bread['url']))
            <li>{!! link_to($bread['url'], $bread['name']) !!}</li>
        @else
            <li>{!! $bread['name'] !!}</li>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    </ol>
@endif
```

and connect it to layout

```
@include('breadcrumbs')
```

and in your action pass array of links

```
\View::share('breadcrumbs', [
        ['url' => route('collection.show', ['id'=>$data->collection, 'url'=>$data->collection]), 'name' => $data->collection->name],
        ['name' => $data->article]
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, first of all Yurich. I have a layout and more than 150 routes (its a big application), do I have to switch the render function for the casuistic of every route?

Comment: that's why i refuse to use this practice and make my own practice

Comment: Thanks a lot, you so kind. I am so grateful.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way. As general, in each view just calling `Breadcrumbs::render()` should create the hierarchy of the breadcrumbs links depending on the routes defined in `routes/breadcrumbs.php`.

There are two essential points that you have keep in mind to go further with this solution:

1. The callback function that found in `breadcrumbs.php` routs definition is the place from which you should pass your parameters.
2. Giving correct name to your web route from `routes/web.php` which will be used later in `routes/breadcrumbs.php`

Checkout the following code snippets that demonstrates the above two points:

```
//Point1: routes/breadcrumbs.php

Breadcrumbs::register('job.edit', function($breadcrumbs, $job, $title)
{
    $breadcrumbs->parent('job','job');  
    $breadcrumbs->push($title, route('job.edit', $job));
});
Breadcrumbs::register('job.edit.install', function($breadcrumbs, $job, $title)
{   
    $breadcrumbs->parent('job.edit',$job, $title);  
    $breadcrumbs->push('Job Install Equipments', route('job.edit.install','job'));
});
```

In the above code we passed `$job` and `$title` through the callback function.

```
//Point2 routes/web.php
Route::get('/job/edit/{job}', 'JobController@edit')->name('job.edit');
Route::get('/job/install-equipments/{job}', 'JobController@installEquipments')->name('job.edit.install');
```

We give a name to the route through the `name` method , Laravel 5.4, which allow us to define the routes correctly in Point1.

The last step, is what you have do in the view file. Here I will show you the last one regarding `/job/install-equipments` which should be rendered in the breadcrumb as the last element and its parent is `job/edit` with parameter `job` which handles the primary key `id`

```
//install.equipments.blade.php
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
{!! Breadcrumbs::render('job.edit.install',$job->id, __('Edit').': '.$job->title) !!}
```

The above will render a breacrumbs look like:

> [Home](http://Home) / [Job](http://Home/job) / [Edit: title of
>   job](http://Home/job/edit/24) / Job Install Equipment

The required parameters that handles breadcrumbs render are supplied un the above `render` method i.e through `$job->id` and `__('Edit').': '.$job->title)` , the last just adjusting the text and it could be done inside the callback function of `breadcrumbs` routes.

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51923316/how-can-i-pass-parameter-using-dynamic-breadcrums-laravel