# How can I pass parameter using dynamic breadcrums laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.6, breadcrumbs

My breadcrumbs view like this :

```
Home / Dashboard / Summary / Summary Detail
```

If link summary detail is active, the url link like this :

```
http://my-app.test/admin/summary-detail?item_number=123&vendor_code=V123&from_date=2018-01-01&to_date=2018-08-01
```

If I click link summary, the url like this :

```
http://my-app.test/admin/summary
```

I want if I click link summary, it will get all parameter from summary detail. So I want the url like this :

```
http://my-app.test/admin/summary?item_number=123&vendor_code=V123&from_date=2018-01-01&to_date=2018-08-01
```

How can I do it?

**Note**

I use dynamic breadcrumbs

documentation : https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs

In my `\routes\breadcrumbs\summary.php` like this :

```
<?php
Breadcrumbs::for('admin.summary.index', function ($trail) {
    $trail->parent('admin.dashboard');
    $trail->push(__('Summary'), route('admin.summary.index'));
});
Breadcrumbs::for('admin.summary-detail.index', function ($trail) {
    $trail->parent('admin.summary.index');
    $trail->push(__('Summary Detail'), route('admin.summary-detail.index'));
});
```

I using `{!! Breadcrumbs::render() !!}` in view blade to get it

My routes like this :

```
Route::resource('summary', 'SummaryController');
Route::resource('summary-detail', 'SummaryDetailController');
```

Comment: You might be able to add all the query strings to the end of the URL by using Laravel's `Request::query()`. You might have to play around with it as I'm doing this from memory, but maybe something like `route('...') . '?' . http_build_query(Request::query())`

Comment: There's also `Request::fullUrl()` which might work better. I'm not sure. Frankly, I wouldn't be surprised if the package you're using has support for this sort of thing, but I haven't used it myself.